# Classifying data that seems non linear

Tags: classification, pytorch

The data I am using specifies a series Cartesian coordinates, and velocities and there will be solutions that are fairly closely plotted for all of these... however it also utilizes rotations and the solution to several problems require applications of polar coordinates and the Pythagorean theorem and acceleration over time functions.

There are several factors to consider.  I think it sounds non-linear, the problem not being solveable without tangent functions and the use of exponents and sqrts.  Is my line of reasoning correct for the purpose of what types of layer operations to use in a Neural Net ?

Presently the hidden layers I have coded in PyTorch in the model are linear, what should I be using for classifying and estimating a spatial problem ?

The basis of this is that the solutions between the input and the ouput will start to cluster but the shape is uncertain to me, since its hard to visualize 13 dimensions of data.

Its a game style decision maker, I'm trying to simulate how a person would eye a target and move a big gun around.  So the outputs are just soft flags to tell the program which way to move and how urgently and whether estimation is its out of range or if it might be a good time to fire.

Comment: Have you tried non linear dimensional reduction  algorithms? T-SNE or UMAP for instance. https://distill.pub/2016/misread-tsne/

Comment: Be careful with t-SNE, which cannot be applied to new data like a test or validation set. @NicolasMartin

Comment: Indeed. However, according to the creator "A potential approach to deal with this would be to train a multivariate regressor to predict the map location from the input data."
There are some interesting initiatives like this one: https://github.com/sdpython/mlinsights/blob/master/_doc/notebooks/sklearn/predictable_tsne.ipynb

Comment: ugh i hate the lack of visualization.  @Nicholasmartin I looked at tat example you put up and it uses sklearns model selector.  how well does that work in practice ?